# Why wasn't Tobey Maguire in The Amazing Spider-Man?

Tags: casting, the-amazing-spider-man

In the Spider-Man franchise, [Tobey Maguire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobey_Maguire) is an outstanding performer as a Spider-Man and also reprised his role in the sequels Spider-Man 2, Spider-Man 3. He also provided the voice of Spider-Man for the videogame adaptations of the films, but he wasn't in the recent release of Spider-Man series **[The Amazing Spider-Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0948470)**.

Since his outstanding performance in the Spider-Man series, I was surprised. **Why didn't Tobey Maguire get a chance to act in The Amazing Spider-Man?**

Comment: Because this was another reboot?  Same Michael Keaton wasn't in the Dark Knight movies?

Comment: Personally I would question how outstanding his performances were... Especially in Spiderman 3

Comment: @AlasdairCM - Yeah I never liked Tobey Maguire, and while I like Kirsten Dunst in other movies her Mary Jane wasn't her best.

Comment: In fact I really liked *Andrew Garfield*'s *Peter Parker*. *Tobey Maguire* wasn't bad, but having watched his trilogy ad nauseam the new *Spider-Man* was a welcome change.

Comment: I really preferred Andrew Garfield's performance even though the script wasn't the best. Toby never really convinced me as Spiderman. Too whiny and didn't joke at all...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The new Amazing Spider-Man is a *reboot* of the series. In other words, it has nothing to do with the earlier three movies. A few core elements remain, but the rest have been changed. So it only makes sense since they're giving the franchise a fresh start to give the role of Peter Parker to someone else.

Answer (score 5):

It's a Reboot and reboot with same stars will look dumb. Take the case of Hulk and Batman both movies reboot don't cast the same actors. It's not the hard rule but if we are going to see a reboot then we expecting something new, new story, new angle and obviously new stars too.

Same movie reboot having the exact same script or same stars will look lame and nobody will going to watch it. If It's spider-man 4 then it should be with `Tobey Maguire` but for movie like `The Amazing Spider-Man` which is like starting up a new franchise the same star-cast is not a good decision at all.

Answer (score 0):

Spider-Man is about a young boy. Tobey Maguire was getting older. The innocent face of a young troubled boy was no longer visible in him as it was in part 1 & 2. I mean Spider-Man 3 was such a letdown. That's why he could not be continued to play Spider-Man. And after the relatively dismal performance/reception of Spider-Man 3 the producers decided to start all new.

This is what I think happened.